# Javascript not loading in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

On my Sharepoint 2016 page I have a list and a search function created via Script Editor that filters the list. I have this exact same function working on a Sharepoint 2013 page fine, but on this 2016 page the script doesn't seem to load at the right time and nothing happens when using the search. If I go into edit mode, the search works. Can someone help as to what delay/'don't load the page until the script is ready code' I need to add? Javascript or JQuery will do, the script is loading a local library which I left out. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 var list = $("table.ms-listviewtable");
 // Loads the list from table
 var listItems = $("table.ms-listviewtable tr:not(.ms-viewheadertr)");
 // Filters the table
 var input = $("input#filterInput");

 input.keyup(function() // When typing the search box, the function runs...
 {
 //Insert line or function here to convert first letter to uppercase?

    listItems.each(function() // For every item in the catalogue
 {
var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // Load all the text values

if (text.indexOf(input.val().toLowerCase()) != -1) // Compare the user input to the text value
{
  $(this).show();// If it matches, show it
}
else
{
  $(this).hide(); // If not, hide it
}
 });
});

});

</script>​​​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled [Minimal Download Strategy feature.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/minimal-download-strategy-overview) for your site?

The URL looks like `/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/your page`.

If the feature is enabled, you could try to disable it and confirm whether your custom script could be loaded.

Or

Save the code in an html page, then insert a content editor on the page and import the html page through the Content Editor's Content Link.

[image]

Comment: Disabling minimal download strategy seems to have fixed it, many thanks! the Content Editor link didn't work, but I'm pretty happy with leaving MDS turned off.